# npm package installation error (express, ember)

Tags: express, npm-install

I've been trying to install ember and express in my windows 8.1 for learning. I face the similar error in both packages ember and express while using the following command.

`npm install -g express-generator`

I have attached the cmd error page for better understanding of the error. I am new to express and ember, just now starting to learn please help me out.
thanks.[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZeIv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Open and admin command line (Run as administrator) then and execute your commands.

You need elevated permissions to install globally (-g), that's the cause of your errors.

Comment: I tried to run it as admin, still i am not able to install express js. Is there any step by step procedure explaining sites for installing express js in windows ? I am new to this field, please don't mistake me if this is a simple process.

Comment: @ChintuKarthi Try upgrading nodejs to latest version, you're using 6.11 and current is 8.9